# Help with fire code in a condo building

Tags: code-compliance

We had a "contractor" come out to bid our project and told me I needed to cut the drywall off one side of our living room wall. (We live on the 15th floor of a condo building in Minneapolis MN.) I did and then he bailed on the job, I have since had others out and the latest one said the wall needs to be re-drywalled due to fire code. What is the rule here in regards to a residential wall between living room and bedroom with some electrical and a sprinkler pipe running through it? 
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Please explain... it sounds like you were told to remove drywall for some unstated reason, and now you do not wish to replace it. Do you actually **want** to have an open exposed unfinished wall in your living room? You are asking whether or not this is allowed by code?

Answer (score 1):

Generally fire code will require that any exposed wiring (not run through metal conduit) be behind sheet rock or some other wall board.

I would imagine the same is true for plumbing.

The logic here is that you can't pull, bump or otherwise disrupt wires and pipes if they are behind a wall.

I don't know the particulars of code in MSP BUT I can't imagine that they allow exposed pipes and wiring.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is sheetrock required to protect NM-type wiring from physical damage, the sheetrock itself is the primary source of fire resistance in a light-frame (wood or steel stud) wall -- without it, fire can directly get into the structural members and mess them up in a hurry!  So get that drywall replaced ASAP.